# Monitor task in background

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, task, background-process

I am looking at creating code that all of my windows services will use to write a "heartbeat" to a database table to allow me to create a montior app to raise awareness of when a service is not up.

To this end I've created a ServiceHeartbeat project with a single class, Heartbeat, to find my service record in the database and added a timer to execute every minute like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to perform the registering of a services' "heartbeat"
/// </summary>
public class Heartbeat
{
    private readonly string _serviceName;
    private IService _service;
    private readonly IServiceRepository _serviceRepository;
    private readonly Timer _timer = new Timer();
    private bool continueBeating = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Heartbeat(string serviceName)
        :this(new ServiceRepository(new ConnectionFactory()))
    {
        _serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    internal Heartbeat(IServiceRepository serviceRepository)
    {
        _serviceRepository = serviceRepository;
    }


    public async Task<IService> GetSvc(string serviceName)
    {
        var svc = await _serviceRepository.FindByServiceNameAsync(_serviceName);

        return svc;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Begin inserting heartbeat record into monitor database
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            _service = _serviceRepository.FindByServiceNameAsync(_serviceName).Result;
            if (_service != null)
            {
                _timer.Interval = _service.HeartbeatIntervalMins * 60 * 1000;
                _timer.Enabled = true;
                _timer.AutoReset = true;
                _timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    RegisterHeartbeat();
                };
                _timer.Start();
                while (continueBeating)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stop registering service heartbeat in monitor database
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        continueBeating = false;
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }

    private void RegisterHeartbeat()
    {
        _serviceRepository.RegisterHeartbeat(_service.Id);
    }
}
```

This is updating the record I am interested in but due to my While(continueBeating) statement I block thread so any service which news up my Heartbeat class and calls Start() is not going to continue with it's own functionality as my start is never going to return.

How can I make my heartbeat class start and run in background, repeatedly until service is faulted/stopped, whilst consuming code in my service continues it's execution?

Comment: why do you have the loop and a timer?

Comment: also windows services have health support provided by windows

Comment: Nice one Daniel. The timer was because I had added a "test harness" console app project to call whilst dev'ing and was finishing as soon as Start returned. Have moved my wait condition into console app and works. Cheers